# Dynamically update range inside loop by overload end() method

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdvector, range-based-loop

I want to create a class to store data also dynamically - inside a range based loop. But I face problem to overload `end()` method. The idea is something like:

```
template<typename T>
class ContainerClass
{
public:
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin()
    {
        return _v.begin();
    }

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator end()
    {
        return _v.end();
    }

    void add(T a)
    {
        _v.push_back(a);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _v;
};

int main()
{
    ContainerClass<int> c;      
    c.add(1);
    c.add(2); 

    for (auto e : c)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;

        if(input())
           c.add(3);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific what is the question?

Comment: Yep. It seems (I keep researching) I need to create some special iterator for this kind of purpose and return it in begin() and end() overloads. But I'm open for other ideas too.

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears because of range-based for loop implementation.
Possible implementation from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
{
   auto && __range = range_expression ;
   for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
      range_declaration = *__begin;
      loop_statement
   }
}
```

End pointer declares only at the beginning. When you add new element to the array inside the loop it allocates more memory and it leads to undefined behavior. If you `reserve()` more memory before `for (auto e : c)` it will output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: I can not change anything inside or before loop. This is the idea! This class I will use in other code with standard loops.

Comment: @Assen Then don't use range-based loop.But you still need to allocate more memory for _v vector. You can do it inside constructor.

Comment: useless. Vector alone is good enough for what you write.